# How do i delete all from two tables?

Tags: php, sql-delete

I am new to this website (just signed up).
its a simple mysql/php query but for the life of me i can not seem to get my head around it.

How do I delete all from TWO TABLES with one function (see my current coding)?

```
  $id = session_id();
  return mysql_query("DELETE FROM `basket_item` AND `postage` WHERE `session_id` = '$id'");
```

Thanks all for replies :D

Comment: delete just selected rows or completely empty the table? If you want to completely empty a table use `truncate table` as you're sql query, if you want to delete just specific rows your query above is actually correct just run it twice once for each table.

Comment: WARNING: mysql_* is deprecated and should be replaced with the mysqli and PDO APIs and methods.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response @dave I would like to delete specific rows (where the sessionid = $session_id) in a table and i need it as one function. when you say "run it twice" do you mean create two separate functions?

Answer (score 1):

It should have been `mysql_query("DELETE FROM basket_item WHERE session_id = '$id'");`. Note that session_id function may return an empty string and this may cause some trouble. Also, note that on order to use it like this, session_id column in you table needs to have a string type, not integer. Otherwise, you need to perform a cast:

```
$id = (int)session_id();
mysql_query("DELETE FROM basket_item WHERE session_id = $id");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Although i do not understand your answer. I do not have my session_id as a integer because it contacts letters as well as numbers. 

my table structure for session_id is set as a VARCHAR which is acceptable.

Comment: You may have had the session_id column as integer, and i mentioned that to avoid other problems. Yes, it is acceptable as varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single query without having to make two separate queries. You can quite literally separate each table name with a comma as you would a select statement, or anything else.

DELETE FROM table1,table2 where id=1;

If you feel like reading up on it, it's in the MySQL docs:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply @zarathuztra but i have implemented your answer and still got no luck. (below is the change).

function startagain () {

  $id = session_id();
  return mysql_query("DELETE FROM basket_item, postage WHERE `session_id` = '$id'");

}

Comment: What is the actual output from the result set? Any errors reported?

Comment: nope, no errors have come to light. The result is it proceeds to the next page as it should BUT it does not actually delete anything. Bizarre i know!

I have the function running through a php file which is called when you press submit [empty basket] and by <form = "startagain.php" method="post"> then return to the index page.

the method works but the actual it self does not! Any suggestions??

Comment: Nothing is actually deleted you say? What is the datatype of your session_id column? One other thing to try is putting back ticks ` around your table names. Just good practice, and sometimes puts an end to goofy results.

Comment: Nope, nothing has been deleted. My datatype is set as VARCHAR in my mysql table

Comment: also the backticks did not work any wonders too... 

I always get stuck on the codes that are like nearly impossible to fix . "sigh"

Comment: I hear ya bro, it's probably some tiny thing we're both missing :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do 2 completely separate function calls to delete from each table separately, as the tables don't seem to be related, other than by sessionid

Answer (score 0):

you can try inner join:

```
DELETE basket_item , postage  FROM postage  INNER JOIN basket_item  
WHERE postage.session_id = basket_item.session_id and session_id = '$id'
```

or you can execute queries by seperating with semi-colan has same effect and run once:

```
DELETE FROM basket_item WHERE session_id = '$id'; DELETE FROM postage WHERE session_id = '$id';
```